How to Handle SQL Update with Indefinite Number of Exclusion Columns?
I'm working on updating a large SQL database and need to manage dynamic exclusions specified in a comma-separated list within the exclude_fkidval column. Below is the structure of the table before applying the SQL update.
Initial table structure:



id
fkidval
bal
exclude_fkidval




r1
fv10

fv100


r2
fv11

fv111


r3
fv12

fv123


r4
fv13

fv134



Current query:
UPDATE tab
SET bal = (SELECT credit - debit
           FROM f_tab
           WHERE f_tab.fkval LIKE fkidval || '%' 
             AND f_tab.fkval <> exclude_fkidval)

Given that the exclusions in exclude_fkidval might expand indefinitely, I need to adapt the SQL update to handle dynamically varying numbers of exclusions as illustrated below:



id
fkidval
bal
exclude_fkidval




r1
fv10

fv100, fv101, fv102


r2
fv11

fv111


r3
fv12

fv123, fv120


r4
fv13

fv134



Question
How can I efficiently adapt this SQL update query to manage multiple exclusions from the comma-separated exclude_fkidval in each row, considering this impacts a large dataset?

Good practice would be to not use delimited lists and, instead, use a separate table to store the exclusions.
However (if you are stuck with your current implementation), you can compare sub-strings in the list (including the surrounding delimiters):
UPDATE tab
SET bal = (
    SELECT credit - debit
    FROM   f_tab
    WHERE  f_tab.fkval LIKE fkidval || '%'
    AND    ', ' || exclude_fkidval || ', ' NOT LIKE '%, ' || f_tab.fkval || ', %'
)


That is a very good approach. I didn't think of surrounding the search string with identifiers. Works like a charm. Thanks for the help
